# linking gzipped js with an htm page in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net-ajax

i gzipped javascript file using gzip tool and placed it in my asp.net project. Now I want to link this compressed js with an htm page in the sameproject. I tried

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Communicator.js.gz"></script>
```

but is not working... Is there any way to link them??

Comment: Why would you manually gzip your JS file? Your web server is supposed to do it. That's why it's not working.

Comment: Instead of gziping, you can configure your server( container ) for auto zipping.eg change server.xml file for tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

Although unusual it is possible to do this apparently:

> [gZip your JavaScript](http://blog.alien109.com/2009/03/17/gzip-your-javascript/)

Once you've compressed your scripts you may need to add a rewrite rule to tell the browser what to do in your `.htaccess` (or equivalent) file:

```
AddEncoding gzip .gz
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !Safari
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.gz -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.gz [QSA,L]
```

This is assuming you're running `mod_rewrite` or a `mod_rewrite` alike rewriter (such as ISAPI_Rewrite3 on IIS).

If you're running on IIS7.x then you would need to create an IIS7 UrlRewrite rule which would look something like:

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" pattern="gzip" ignoreCase="false" />
          <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="Safari" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}.gz" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.gz" appendQueryString="true" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

The rule above was generated by IIS7's UrlRewrite `mod_rewrite` import tool and is untested.

As I said above this would be a fairly unusual situation because most web servers are now configured to deflate or compress content if they can.